# Copy & Delete Function on Sheets w/ Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After someone submits a Google Form response, their responses go to the DropRequests sheet (although the form is not currently linked for reasons).

What we want to do is after someone submits their form, and their responses go to the DropRequests sheet, that if the value in column C matches that of column F in the StudentMatches sheet, it is moved to the OldMatches sheet. We have started on the code below but it does not yet work. Any ideas on how to make this functional and fix the issue with the range in the last line?

```
function moveMatch(){
var oldmatches = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OldMatches");
var droprequest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DropRequests");
var currentmatches = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dd9UhD2LpshCFVYizpf3OwI1XzPrq3AfqhMAO1iJ6Ns')

  value1 =  currentmatches.getRange("F:F").getDisplayValues();
  value2 = droprequest.getRange("C:C").getDisplayValues();

for(var i in value1)
  if(value2[0,i]=value1){
  
  currentmatches.getDataRange.getRow(0,i).moveTo(oldmatches.getLastRow())
}
}
```

Thank you again.

Comment: This is not the type of forum to offer payments for scripts through your question.  If users provide you with information via their profile then that is between you and them.  I removed your solicitations and if you replace them I'll flag the question for moderator intervention.

Comment: Ok, sorry! We're not familiar with all the rules, so appreciate you helping us out.

Comment: Gotcha, we tried to update our code. Please let us know if this is more clear.

Comment: I think more clarification is needed because the code provided would try to do something completely different to what you mentioned that you want to accomplish. If I understand correctly you currently have some information in StudentMatches and you want to copy that information to OldMatches and then remove it from StudentMatches. Now you also mention DropRequests, but I don't really get the usage of it in this scenario. Could you add more clarification?

Comment: Your provided Spreadsheets are the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? Because I cannot imagine `What we want to do is after someone submits their form, and their responses go to the DropRequests sheet, that their corresponding information in this StudentMatches sheet is copied to the OldMatches sheet and deleted from the StudentMatches sheet.`. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion! When someone submits a "Drop request," meaning they want to drop their student, it goes to the DropRequests sheet (form responses, col C). Then, if that request matches a value in col F of StudentMatches, we want to move that row from col F of StudentMatches to OldMatches, then delete that row from Student Matches. I hope this helps! It sounds complex, but it's very useful for our program management.

Comment: We've combined the sheets to make it easier. Perhaps just a moveTo function would do the trick now? We have updated our code and to reflect this change. Hopefully this will simplify things.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When `moveTo` is used, the moved row becomes the empty row. Is this your expected result?

Comment: Yes, that's what we hope to do! However, the current code doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- There are 3 sheets `DropRequests`, `StudentMatches`, `OldMatches` in your Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the values of column "C" from `DropRequests` sheet, and want to compare these values with the values of column "F" of `StudentMatches` sheets.
- When the values are matched, you want to move the row from the `StudentMatches` sheet to the 1st empty row of `OldMatches` sheet.
- When `moveTo` is used, the moved row becomes the empty row. In your goal, you want this situation.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function moveMatch() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("DropRequests");
  var srcSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("StudentMatches");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OldMatches");

  var srcValues1 = srcSheet1.getRange("C2:C" + srcSheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([c]) => c);
  var [,...srcValues2] = srcSheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values = srcValues2.flatMap((r, i) => srcValues1.includes(r[5]) ? i + 2 : []);
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  var lastCol = srcSheet2.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  values.forEach((r, i) => srcSheet2.getRange(r, 1, 1, lastCol).moveTo(dstSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1 + i, 1)));
}
```

- In this modification, the values are retrieved from the column "C" of "DropRequests" and "StudentMatches". And, the values of the column "C" of "DropRequests" are compared with the column "F" of "StudentMatches" sheet. When the values are matched, the row is moved from "StudentMatches" to "OldMatches".

#### Note:

- First, please check the sheet names, again.
- This sample script is for your question. So, when the Spreadsheet is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [moveTo(target)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget)

Comment: This works splendidly! Thank you so much @Tanaike for your diligence and help!

Comment: @Progress Point Tutoring Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.